# what is the meaning of "pilot_duplicate_envoy_clusters" in istio pilot logs

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-kiali

I have an service Entry kind which is for the database service in other namespace(istio-enabled=false).
Now the question is

1. why am i getting pilot_duplicate_envoy_clusters in pilot logs?
2. what does it mean really?
3. Where will i get the proper documentation?

```
 "ProxyStatus": {
        "pilot_duplicate_envoy_clusters": {
            "outbound|5432||test-pgdb-pgbouncer.test-db.svc.cluster.local": {
                "proxy": "istio-ingressgateway-6bcd9c685c-r5z7k.istio-system",
                "message": "Duplicate cluster outbound|5432||test-pgdb-pgbouncer.test-db.svc.cluster.local found while pushing CDS"
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Hi, this is not documented except for a single github issue [post](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14036). Can you paste `ServiceEntry` yaml ? Also which istio version do You use?

Comment: istio version 1.4.8